# Power BI See All Data Sources (SQL objects used in reports)

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

How can I search all Power BI reports for an instance of a view, stored procedure, table
being used?

We have SQLSearch for SSMS, was looking for something similar for Power BI.

I see search one report for data sources, but not all power bi reports for a specific data source.